# How do I assign a vector to a subset of rows of a column in a pandas DataFrame with NaNs?

Tags: python, pandas

i'm having trouble assigning to a DataFrame column for a subset of rows, if there are NaNs in the DataFrame.  i can't tell, is this a bug or am i misunderstanding something?

first off, if there are no NaNs, what i want appears to work :

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> d = pd.DataFrame({ 'one' : [1, 2, 3], 'two' : [1,2,3] })
>>> d
   one  two
0    1    1
1    2    2
2    3    3
>>> d.ix[d['one']>1, 'two'] = -d['two']
>>> d
   one  two
0    1    1
1    2   -2
2    3   -3
```

however, adding nuisance NaN rows causes non-intuitive results :

```
>>> nan = float('nan')
>>> d = pd.DataFrame({ 'one' : [1, 2, 3, nan, nan], 'two' : [1,2,3,4,5] })
>>> d
   one  two
0    1    1
1    2    2
2    3    3
3  NaN    4
4  NaN    5
>>> d.ix[d['one']>1, 'two'] = -d['two']
>>> d
   one  two
0    1    1
1    2   -2
2    3   -2
3  NaN    4
4  NaN    5
```

what is going on here? this is with Python 2.7.5 and pandas 0.11.

Comment: [Oh, I see -- it's the second `-2`.]

Comment: This is fixed in dev (0.11.1) out very soon.

Comment: @AndyHayden: I was just looking up the issue #.  Do you have it at hand?

Comment: @DSM not 100% tbh, but I think I've found it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3668) in 0.11 and has since been fixed in dev (so will be in 0.11.1, out soon).

*Thanks for reporting, this test case <del>will be</del> [has been added to pandas](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/3858) testing suite.*